# How do i make vim statusline like spacemacs line?

Tags: vim

How do i make vim statusline like spacemacsline, Same as in the picture，Can anyone help to achieve ? Thanks a lot

[image: spacemacsline]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. Do you already have a statusline plugin (like _airline_)? That would be important information that's currently missing from your answer.

Comment: Hi i  used vim-airline vim-lightline, But their appearance can't be like the picture。
I just used vim for 6 months. A new vimer， I can use vim skillfully, but the setting of vim is just beginning to learn.I am trying to make a statusline myself, but a lot of things are not very clear, so I am looking for help. If it can be done for me and the look on the picture is great, I can try to write their own functions.

Comment: vim-airline maintainer here: I am pretty sure, you can customize vim-airline the way you want,  read the documentation. But honestly, I find that look very unpleasant to the eye and confusing. Since you are a new vimmer, you might be better of by using the SpaceVim distribution, that comes with a custom statusline (I believe a heavily patched airline)

Comment: I have read the documentation, airline provides a lot of settings, but the symbol settings can only be set once on the left and right. I want to make vim's statusline the same as spacemacs, the picture looks like。I don't like spacevim, I have split my configuration well.